# How can I set image in middle ( center allign ) during printing in html css?

Tags: html, css, web, printing

Any one please tell me how can I set this image in center allign for print?

I am using paid plugin "Real 3d Flipbook".

**Below is a image.**

[image]

Comment: Instead of hyperlink for image, you can put image in question for more readability.

Comment: click on link you can see image.

Answer (score 0):

Use media = print in style tag and define css to positioning margin and padding. e.g.

```
<style media="print">
   img{
      align:center;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: I don't think there's a CSS property called `align`.